Question to Mods -- are you able to change the number of allowed questions per unit time for members?
Mods,
As a partial solution to our current site conflict over Voting to Close, several members have suggested a reduction in allowed questions by users per unit time.
Currently, that limit appears to be 6/day.
Are you able to change that number globally for the site?  To, say 1/day, or 3/week, or 1/week?
If so, would you be willing to try such a change on an evaluation basis, to see if it cools tempers here?
All others, we have had a partial discussion on this in the comments on this answer:   https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6137/29339 but our mods may benefit from a more in-depth set of comments.
For reference, two of the users who have been the targets of VTC due to excessive posting average approximately 10 questions each per week over the last three weeks.

I think this would also help to encourage less sophisticated users to think through instead of just popping in and asking a question.

@JD I believe it will also provide a better impression for new users. A new user is glancing at a site looking at the current questions. If the site is dominated daily by a few users, then those users become the "welcome wagon" for newbies. Those users questions become a template for new users and problems spread quickly.

With the disruption on the board that two posters only posting at a rate ~ 1/4 of the max allowed rate cause, I think our max allowed rate of 6/day is very detrimental to the board, and should be reduced.  As the disruption is happening with only about 1.5/day, I also think that reducing the limit to only 1/day would not protect the board from similar disruption.   That is why I endorsed shifting the limit to a "per week" criteria, with the max I would recommend our mods considering of 3/week.  1/week might work better, but could have downsides becasue of our "focused question" criteria.

@Dcleve I'm 100% behind 1/week because a good question should simmer in the crockpot awhile, but ultimately, it might be worthy of a vote after an RFC.

@JD I agree that there should be a lot more time taken to understand questions compared to how some users are posting, but 1/week does seem a bit excessive to me, especially as a change from the current rules.  Lowering the (potential) asking rate by 42x seems like a really big move.  Probably best to start with something closer to 1/day or 3/week or something, at least initially.

@JMac That's a fair concern. As the mods haven't responded at all, it might not be any concern ultimately. :D

@JMac I am also concerned with unexpected consequences, and am a little leery of dropping to 1/week.  However, the disruption from ~10/week would not be mitigated much by a limit of only 7/week, so the 1/day, while a big change in the rules, I fear would not be a big enough change on the board given current practice.  My recommendation is to try the 3/week and see if it makes the board less contentious.
